# How to check whether something is a movie title, using a SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, owl, dbpedia

I want write a query in SPARQL in which if we provide any input name, query result will tell whether or not it is a film title. For example --

```
select distinct ?type where {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Inception> a ?type .
FILTER regex(str(?type), "^.*movie", "i") }
```

Query result tells us that it is a movie. Now when we enter those names having ambiguities, it will return nothing.

For example, if we enter `Captain_Phillips` in place of `Inception`, it returns -- nothing.

So, I wonder how to get whether a name is movie title or not in ambiguous case.

Comment: Do you have an example that doesn't work? Or what is the problem now? And why can't you ask whether the resource belongs to the class `dbo:Film` or `schema:Movie`?

Answer (score 0):

http://dbpedia.org/resource/Captain_Phillips is about the person, not the Movie. http://dbpedia.org/resource/Captain_Phillips_(film) is of type scehma:Movie.

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
?type 
WHERE 
{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Captain_Phillips_(film)> a ?type.

FILTER (regex(str(?type), "^.*movie", "i")). 
}
```

If you solely want to check that results exist:

```
ASK
{
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Captain_Phillips_(film)> a ?type.

FILTER (regex(str(?type), "^.*movie", "i")). 
}
```